# Magento query to sort products alphabetically

Tags: magento2, product-list, querystring

Does anyone know if there is a query string to sort products alphabetically within the product list

```
?product_list_order=position
?product_list_order=price
```

The above works but the below doesn't?

```
?product_list_order=desc
?product_list_order=asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
?product_list_dir=asc&product_list_order=name
```